# How to add spinner in a dialog box in jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

```
jQ.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : url,
    cache : false,

    success : function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        // jQ("<div></div>").attr('id', 'dvShiftDialog').appendTo('body');
        jQ('#main').html(jQ(msg));

        jQ('#dvShiftDialog').dialog({
            title : 'Confirm',
            modal : true,
            draggable : true,
            resizable : true,
            width : 525,
            height : 625,

            close : function() {
                jQ('#dvShiftDialog').dialog("destroy");
                jQ('#dvShiftDialog').remove();
                jQ('div.ui-dialog').remove();
            }
        });
    },
    error : function(err) {
        var m = "Error: " + err.status + '    ' + err.statusText;
        window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

according to http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ (which is i assume what you are using) you can put anything in the dialog box. so just use a `.gif` image somewhere inside the `div` tag (or what ever you are using for the dialog) and it should do the trick

Comment: how to add some text message before loading dialog here

Comment: @user1551357 sorry im not exactly sure what you are asking.